# How to use change position in HTML with radio and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I must use change the page if radioButton value is "Yes"

Location is wrong - Why?

How can I go to affidatario.php if radioButton value is "si"?

```js
function controlla() {
  x = document.prova;
  if (x.scelta.value == "si") {
    location('../affidatario.php')
    return false;
  }
  if (x.scelta.value == "no") {
    alert("Hai risposto no");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="?" method="POST" name="prova" onsubmit="return controlla();">
  SI<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="si" /><br /> NO
  <input type="radio" name="scelta" value="no" /><br />
  <button type="submit">INVIA</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = url`

Comment: Or `window.location.assign('url')`

Comment: Vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: `document.querySelector("[name=prova]").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {  e.preventDefault(); if (this.scelta.value == "si") 
    location= '../affidatario.php';

  else
    alert("Hai risposto no");
});`

Answer (score 1):

just change the line `location('../affidatario.php')` to `location.href=someurl.php`;

```js
function controlla() {
  x = document.prova;
  if (x.scelta.value == "si") {
    location.href='https://google.com';
    return false;
  }
  if (x.scelta.value == "no") {
    alert("Hai risposto no");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="?" method="POST" name="prova" onsubmit="return controlla();">
  SI<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="si" /><br /> NO
  <input type="radio" name="scelta" value="no" /><br />
  <button type="submit">INVIA</button>
</form>
```